# CSS Grid layout height and scrollbar don't work right

Tags: html, css, css-grid

CSS

```css
.site {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 10% 60% 20%;
  grid-gap: 10px;


  grid-template-areas:
  "header header"
  "nav bar"
  "nav content"
  "nav description";
}

.page-title{
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.navbar{
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: grey;
}

.bar_content{
  grid-area: bar;
  background-color: orange;
}

.main{
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: red;
}

.explanation{
  grid-area: description;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Ressourcenplannung</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="site">

      <header class="page-title">
          <img src="Konami.png" width="20%">
      </header>

      <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Mitarbeiter</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Arbeiten / Projekte</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Auslastungdiagnose Woche</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Auslastungdiagnose Tag</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>

      <bar class="bar_content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
           sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </bar>
      
      <content class="main">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Vorname</th>
            <th>Nachname</th>
            <th>Geburtsdatum</th>
            <th>Pensum in %</th>
            <th>Anstellungsverhälnis</th>
            <th>Vertragsende</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>26.07.1985</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Vollzeit</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Aaron</td>
            <td>Solo</td>
            <td>26.07.1996</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Lehrling</td>
            <td>31.08.2019</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>26.07.1985</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Vollzeit</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Aaron</td>
            <td>Solo</td>
            <td>26.07.1996</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Lehrling</td>
            <td>31.08.2019</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>26.07.1985</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Vollzeit</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Aaron</td>
            <td>Solo</td>
            <td>26.07.1996</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Lehrling</td>
            <td>31.08.2019</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </content>
      
      <description class="explanation">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
         sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </description>
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I had two question I tried to make a simple layout with grid the cells works fine just:
Why there is displayed a scollbar in the bottom?

Why the grid don't use the full size of the window when I have defined the sizes of the columns and rows.

Comment: I fixed my problem here the CSS:
.site {
  display: grid;
  width: auto;
  height: 95vh;
  grid-template-columns: auto 80%;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 10% 60% 20%;
  grid-gap: 1vh;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header header"
  "nav bar"
  "nav content"
  "nav description";
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lower the grid gap, it should fix your issue. By using 20% and 80%, you aren't really leaving any room for margins (or grid gaps) on the page. It can sometimes push a margin or padding off the screen, which will make a scroll bar appear.

```css
.site {
  position: absolute;
  height: 98%;
  margin-right: 10px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 80%;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 10% auto 20%;
  grid-gap: 10px;


  grid-template-areas:
  "header header"
  "nav bar"
  "nav content"
  "nav description";
}

.page-title{
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.navbar{
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: grey;
}

.bar_content{
  grid-area: bar;
  background-color: orange;
}

.main{
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: red;
}

.explanation{
  grid-area: description;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Ressourcenplannung</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="site">

      <header class="page-title">
          <img src="Konami.png" width="20%">
      </header>

      <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Mitarbeiter</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Arbeiten / Projekte</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Auslastungdiagnose Woche</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Auslastungdiagnose Tag</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>

      <bar class="bar_content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
           sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </bar>
      
      <content class="main">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Vorname</th>
            <th>Nachname</th>
            <th>Geburtsdatum</th>
            <th>Pensum in %</th>
            <th>Anstellungsverhälnis</th>
            <th>Vertragsende</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>26.07.1985</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Vollzeit</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Aaron</td>
            <td>Solo</td>
            <td>26.07.1996</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Lehrling</td>
            <td>31.08.2019</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>26.07.1985</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Vollzeit</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Aaron</td>
            <td>Solo</td>
            <td>26.07.1996</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Lehrling</td>
            <td>31.08.2019</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>26.07.1985</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Vollzeit</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Aaron</td>
            <td>Solo</td>
            <td>26.07.1996</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Lehrling</td>
            <td>31.08.2019</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </content>
      
      <description class="explanation">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
         sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </description>
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx, it didn't help but still thx^^. I found the issue 1 i set the columns to;  auto 80%; But i still don't understand why it don't use the full height size of the page

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment. To have the grid take up the entire height of the page, you need to add position: absolute and height:100%. I also added an auto to the grid rows to help get rid of the scroll bar and a margin-right to keep the gap around the outside.